# how can i make a circle that fades in trasparency

Tags: javascript, alpha

I want to make an earthquake effect by using transparent-insides circles that rapidly get bigger, is there a way to do this instead of making circles with different alphas 100s of times? I have already searched this up but it only gave me fully transparent circles

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using gradients?

```
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

Comment: JavaScript plz no css or html

Comment: It's very unlikely you'll get an answer that uses purely JavaScript to achieve what you're describing, as JS isn't responsible for dictating how page elements are rendered. On the other hand, CSS is responsible. You can define these styles in a CSS class, then use JavaScript to apply it to whatever element you need, but that's as far as you can get with purely JS.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut i don't  mean a html element that is  a circle shape, I mean a "canvas rendering 2d" circle, that is why i did not include CSS or html in my tags but instead i did JavaScript

Comment: In that case, you should edit your question to make that clearer. Canvas elements aren't mentioned anywhere in your question.

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut i have  the js tag but not the html tag